# Create a logical variable that will be TRUE if the toyprice is 10 or more

Tags: r

I have to create a logical variable that will be TRUE if the `toyprice` is 10 or more.
I don't know how to declare 10 or more will be TRUE in R.

Could you explain how to do so?

ex) toyprice 11 will be TRUE
toyprice 8 will be FALSE

Comment: Did you read about `?Logic` ?

Comment: `newvar <- toyprice >10`

Comment: Actually, toyprice was numerical data, so I changed to logical using as.logical(toyprice). After that If toyprice is higher than 10, it shows up TRUE, other FALSE. But I don't know how to do.

Comment: You don't want to do `as.logical(toyprice)`. Consider `as.logical(0)`; `as.logical(1)` ...

Comment: @Mike, please post your comment as an answer ...

Comment: @BenBolker just posted, thanks

Answer (score 1):

an efficient way to do that would be:

```
newvar <- toyprice >10
```

This assigns a logical value to `newvar`. If `toyprice` is greater than 10 it will be `TRUE`, otherwise it will be `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where and how `toyprice` is stored. Is it a data frame, a matrix, or a vector? Data frames can contain multiple types of data, such as logical, numeric, and character. It is also important to know how you need to store these results - if just testing, the comment by @Mike is the best way. But typically this may need to be stored alongside the dataset containing the actual price, toy type, etc. So knowing what yourdata structure is will be important for testing for the condition of >= 10 (i.e., logically or dichotomously, as matrices can only contain one type of data).

Below is a basic run-through of how you might achieve this given data frames, matrices, and vectors. Good luck!

### Data Frame

```
#### Data frame
ex_dataframe <- data.frame(toy = c("skates", "rocketship", "scooter"),
                           toycode = 1:3,
                           toyprice = c(10, 11, 7))

# Data frame, as logical
ex_dataframe$gt10_logic <- ex_dataframe$toyprice >= 10
# Data frame, as numeric 1/0
ex_dataframe$gt10_num <- (ex_dataframe$toyprice >= 10)*1

#       toy         toycode toyprice gt10_logic gt10_num
# 1     skates       1       10       TRUE        1
# 2 rocketship       2       11       TRUE        1
# 3    scooter       3        7      FALSE        0
```

### Matrix

```
##### Matrix, only contain one type of data, here numeric
ex_matrix <- matrix(c(1:3,10, 11, 7), ncol = 2)
ex_matrix <- cbind(ex_matrix, ex_matrix[,2] >= 10)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   10    1
# [2,]    2   11    1
# [3,]    3    7    0
```

### Vector

```
#### Vector
ex_vector <- c(10, 11, 7)
gt10_logical <- ex_vector >= 10 # Create logical vector
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

gt10_num <- (ex_vector >= 10)*1 # create dichotomous 1/0
#[1] 1 1 0

# combine to matrix, must be all same type of data
ex_vectorcomb_matrix <- cbind(ex_vector, gt10_num)
#           ex_vector gt10_num
# [1,]        10        1
# [2,]        11        1
# [3,]         7        0

# combine to data frame, can contain multiple types of data (logical, numeric, character)
ex_vectcom_dataframe <- data.frame(toynum = ex_vector, gt10_logical, gt10_num)
#       toynum gt10_logical gt10_num
# 1     10         TRUE        1
# 2     11         TRUE        1
# 3      7        FALSE        0
```